# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `navigation` of type `object` supplied to `ProductDetail`, expected `number`

Tags: react-native

**Failed prop type: Invalid prop `navigation` of type `object` supplied to `ProductDetail`, expected `number`**

I am getting this warning in my console, for following code,

**Home class**

```
this.props.navigation.push('ProductDetail', { screenBottom: result.safeAreaInsets.bottom });
```

**ProductDetail class**

```
static defaultProps = {
    draggableRange: {
      top: (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (height / 1.15) : (height - 80)),
      bottom: (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (height / 3.75) : 146),
    },
    navigation: 0,
}

static propTypes = {
    draggableRange: PropTypes.shape({
      top: PropTypes.number,
      bottom: PropTypes.number,
    }),
    navigation: PropTypes.number,
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.screenBottom = navigation.getParam('screenBottom', 0);
}
```

**Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `navigation` of type `object` supplied to `ProductDetail`, expected `number`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your propTypes, there's probably something like:

> someComponentName.propTypes = {
>       navigation:PropTypes.number
>   }

Comment: Yes, there is... static propTypes = {
    draggableRange: PropTypes.shape({
      top: PropTypes.number,
      bottom: PropTypes.number,
    }),
    navigation: PropTypes.number,
}; However, show warning.

Comment: The navigation prop will never be a number, it's an object. Change .number to .object: `navigation: PropTypes.object`

Comment: Right, I changed to PropTypes.object but eslint show **Prop type `object` is forbiddenes** so I just changed .object to .shape like this **static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.shape({
      screenBottom: PropTypes.number,
    }),
  };** and getting by **const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.screenBottom = navigation.getParam('screenBottom', 0);**